# Magento - 410 Status Header for Deleted Products

Tags: magento, http-status-code-410

My magento store experiences a high amount of products that get added and then deleted. I have been asked to implement a 410 status code on these deleted pages but I am unsure how.

Looking at Magento's core code I can see it handles 404's like so in the core indexController:

```
/**
 * Default index action (with 404 Not Found headers)
 * Used if default page don't configure or available
 *
 */
public function defaultIndexAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Render CMS 404 Not found page
 *
 * @param string $coreRoute
 */
public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null)
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
}

/**
 * Default no route page action
 * Used if no route page don't configure or available
 *
 */
public function defaultNoRouteAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Is there any way I can add a function for a deleted page to send a 410 header?

Comment: Are the products of these deleted pages really deleted from the database or their status is set to Disabled?

Comment: They are completely deleted

Comment: Solution given here by fschmengler: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/410-status-header-for-deleted-products#80246